# How do you calculate the degrees of freedom for the chi-squared distribution for Pearson's chi squared test?

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence, degrees-of-freedom

I am conducting the Pearson's $\chi^2$ test for three variables under the independence model. The data is in a $2 \times 2 \times 2$ contingency table. How do I find the degrees of freedom for $\chi^2$ tables?

Is there a general formula for this?

Is there a formula for more complicated tables?

Comment: You're computing expected values from the marginal product on all three dimensions? $n_Rn_Cn_L/N^2$

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica yes and then find the test statistic by summing this